# How to switch yes and no buttons in dialog box, either in Windows or Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, gnome, cinnamon, dialog

I'm using the Cinnamon DE (based on Gnome 3, uses the GTK3 toolkit) for GNU/Linux.

I also use Windows 10 for approximately the same amount of time each week.

Now, the default button positions for each environment is different, and this is driving me crazy. In MS Windows, the "confirm" action is located on the left:

[image]

While on Cinnamon (and GNOME), they are located on the right:

[image]

This is consistent across all dialogs. Another example:

[image]

In this case, not only the buttons are positioned differently, the action highlighted by default is different too.

Is there any way to change this for either system, so that I can work with more sanity?

Comment: You cant change this behavior on Windows

Comment: @Ramhound I figured

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I highly doubt it is possible to change the button order in Windows, but GTK can! To change the order of the Cancel/No/Yes buttons, set the `gtk-alternative-button-order` property by adding this to your `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` file:

```
[Settings]
gtk-alternative-button-order = 1
```

For some background, the [GNOME Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.gnome.org/hig/stable/dialogs.html.en#order) specify that the cancel button should be on the left:

> When a dialog includes an affirmative and a cancel button, always
>   ensure that the cancel button appears first, before the affirmative
>   button. In left-to-right locales, this is on the left.
>
> This button order ensures that users become aware of, and are reminded
>   of, the ability to cancel prior to encountering the affirmative
>   button.

But it's Linux; so it's configurable! From the [gtk_dialog_set_alternative_button_order() documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkDialog.html#gtk-dialog-set-alternative-button-order):

> Sets an alternative button order. If the
>   “[gtk-alternative-button-order](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkSettings.html#GtkSettings--gtk-alternative-button-order)” setting is set to `TRUE`, the dialog
>   buttons are reordered according to the order of the response ids
>   passed to this function.
>
> By default, GTK+ dialogs use the button order advocated by the [GNOME
>   Human Interface Guidelines](http://library.gnome.org/devel/hig-book/stable/) with the affirmative button at the far
>   right, and the cancel button left of it. But the builtin GTK+ dialogs
>   and [GtkMessageDialogs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkMessageDialog.html#GtkMessageDialog-struct) do provide an alternative button order,
>   which is more suitable on some platforms, e.g. Windows.

The [Windows user experience guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742499(v=vs.85).aspx) have the opposite recommendation. They state:

> Present the commit buttons in the following order:
>
> 1. OK/[Do it]/Yes
> 2. [Don't do it]/No
> 3. Cancel
> 4. Apply (if present)
> 5. Help (if present)

Comment: And the benefit of Cancel being the default action is that in case of inadvertent confirmation by way of accidental Enter or Spacebar keypress, the resulting action is (usually) a no-op.

Comment: The reason why I dislike the GTK convention is simply that everyone says "yes or no" and almost never "no or yes". I’d say naive users expect the affirmative at front and the negative behind it. I remember once affirming something on Linux when trying to cancel as my Windows muscle memory told me: Cancel = Click the right-hand button.